# Encountered IOException while registering python UDF in pig. File helloworld.py does not exist

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

Pytjon UDF :

```
@outputSchema("word:chararray")
def helloworld():
  return 'Hello, World'


register '/user/hdfs/helloworld.py' using jython as myfunc;
```

Error:

```
grunt> REGISTER 'helloworld.py' USING org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;
2016-05-16 12:08:04,909 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File helloworld.py does not exist
2016-05-16 12:08:04,909 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - There is no log file to write to.
2016-05-16 12:08:04,909 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - java.io.FileNotFoundException: File helloworld.py does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFilesInternal(FileLocalizer.java:818)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFile(FileLocalizer.java:756)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerCode(PigServer.java:593)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processRegister(GruntParser.java:467)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:546)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do a `"ls /user/hdfs/helloworld.py"` and check whether the file exists

Comment: Hi Abhi,Thanks for reply. I file is accessible.
:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hdfs/helloworld.py
-rw-r--r--   3 ggk hdfs         77 2016-05-16 11:59 /user/hdfs/helloworld.py

Comment: is it becasue you are not giving full path '/user/hdfs/helloworld.py'  REGISTER 'helloworld.py' USING org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;

Comment: i tried using full path as well. Still getting same error. REGISTER '/user/hdfs/helloworld.py' USING org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;

Comment: For simple registration: REGISTER  '/user/hdfs/helloworld.py',  i am getting an error.

Comment: are you using pig -x local or just pig

Comment: can you place the udf file in local than in hdfs and try? I guess that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: then i have to use pig -x local.

Comment: no for both mapreduce and local it should be in normal filesystem. This was the reason i mentioned ls /user/hdfs/helloworld.py not "hadoop ls"

Comment: thanks vikash, could you please provide me command you are referring to. I got it but it would be better you provide it.

Comment: And if we need to keep UDF in file system then how can we use this for Hadoop.

Comment: I was expecting that you had the python script in local system that was the reason i asked you to check "ls /user/hdfs/helloworld.py"

Comment: that means i need to use pig -x local and then need to register

Comment: pig will take care when you register it will load you need not worry. It should be in the machine were you trigger the script. for both local and mapreduce it will look in local filesystem

Comment: Thanks vikas. I'll summarize what i got. I'll simple use pig. Register using local filepath and then i'll proceed further.

Comment: One more que, i have installed sandbox on my machine but i need to install jython over there. How to install jython in sandbox?

Comment: what flavor of linux is the sandbox?