# ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File foo.py does not exist

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My PIG script has the following line

```
register 'foo.py' USING jython as foo;
```

The file foo.py is present in HDFS root.

but when I run my code I get error

```
ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File foo.py does not exist
```

I did google and found this thread

[Encountered IOException while registering python UDF in pig. File helloworld.py does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248294/encountered-ioexception-while-registering-python-udf-in-pig-file-helloworld-py?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The solution seems to imply that the foo.py must be copied on the local file system to make it work. but that is not an option for me.

I want to copy foo.py on HDFS and then use it from the pig script.

I already tried `register './foo.py' USING jython as foo;` and I can confirm that foo.py is present in the root HDFS directory.

I also tried changing the permissions on the foo.py file to `rwxrwxrwx` but there is no way pig can find that file.

Edit:: Since I am using Hortonworks bistro I also tried to register my UDF in the UDF tab. but It still gives the same error even after registering.

Edit2:: I also copied util.py in the `/user/admin` directory and gave `rwxrwxrwx` permissions. but still can't find the py file.

Edit3:: also tried `register 'hdfs://foo.py' USING jython as util;` but still won't find it.

[image]

Comment: Please show the output of an `hdfs dfs -ls`  command that shows where your file exists (give the absolute path with a leading slash). For example, `/foo.py` would be at `hdfs:///foo.py`. 3 slashes or load `/foo.py`. No dot

Comment: I added a screenshot. you can see foo.py is there

Comment: OK. its working it needed `hdfs:///foo.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the root, you want `/foo.py`

To clarify loading from HDFS, then three slashes are needed `hdfs:///foo.py` (because the full syntax is `hdfs://namenode:port/fileURI`)

Using `./foo.py` implies the root of the *HDFS user folder* for the user running the command